# How to get unmatched elements from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

so i have request coming in that has rxInfos and specialMembers i am getting from cache so if rxInfos.indexID's matched do some processing else if rxInfos indexID is there but for some reason not same as cache indexID i want to push that indexID to mismatchedIndexIDs array. Like 2nd element is rxInfos.indexID is not matching with any of specialMembers so that should pushed to mismatchedIndexIDs.

with below code its pushing all specialMembers ids to unmatched array.

main.ts

```
 for (const member of specialMembers) {
        for (const rxInfo of this.rxInfos) {
            if (member.indexID === rxInfo.indexID) {
                this.indexIDs.push(rxInfo.indexID);
                proxyMember = member;
                if (!member.dateOfBirth) {
                    statusDesc = "member dateOfbirth not found";
                    return Promise.reject(this.errorHandler(request, statusDesc));
                }
                const requestBody: any = this.buildSingleRequestBody(proxyMember, rxInfo);
                const requestObject = this.specialtyQuestionRequest(requestBody);
                this.requestArray.push(requestObject);
            } else {
                this.mismatchIndexIDS.push(rxInfo.indexID);
                this.indexIdMismatchCounter++;
            }
        }
    }
```

data

```
"rxInfos": [
      {
            "drugNdc": "10101",
            "rxNumber": "14556459709",
            "firstFillIndicator": "N",
            "sourceSystem": "TBS",
            "indexID": "RPT0ifQ"
        },
      {
            "drugNdc": "101",
            "rxNumber": "145945000709",
            "firstFillIndicator": "N",
            "sourceSystem": "TBS",
            "indexID": "GJhQ1MrQnZkTFRR"
        }
    ]

    "specialyMembers":[
      {
        "dob":"12-12-1970"
        "firstName": "jimmy",
        "lasteName": "shew",
         "indexID": "RPT0ifQ"
      },
      {
         "dob":"18-10-1970"
        "firstName": "Timmy",
        "lasteName": "Doug",
         "indexID": "GJhQ1MrQ"
      },
        {
         "dob":"17-06-1981"
        "firstName": "John",
        "lasteName": "owascar",
         "indexID": "GJhQ1MrTGDSRQ"
      }
      ]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const memberMatched = member => {
  return rxInfos.find(rxInfo => rxInfo.indexID === member.indexID)
}

const mismatchIndexIDS = specialMembers.reduce((res, member) => {
  return memberMatched(member) ? res : res.concat(member.indexID)
}, [])

const indexIdMismatchCounter = mismatchIndexIDS.length

const matchedMembers = specialMembers.reduce((res, member) => {
  const rxRecord = memberMatched(member)
  return rxRecord ? res.concat({rxRecord, member}) : res
}, [])

// DO YOUR STUFF WITH MATCHED MEMBERS
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a better way to do this with [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) which will directly get the member from `specialMembers` with a certain `indexID`. Moreover, you just have to deal with one `for` loop (the other one is implicit in `find`):

```
specialMembers.find(member => member.indexID === rxInfo.indexID)
```

A simplified version of your `for` loop is as follows:

```js
var rxInfos = [{
    "drugNdc": "10101",
    "rxNumber": "14556459709",
    "firstFillIndicator": "N",
    "sourceSystem": "TBS",
    "indexID": "RPT0ifQ"
  },
  {
    "drugNdc": "101",
    "rxNumber": "145945000709",
    "firstFillIndicator": "N",
    "sourceSystem": "TBS",
    "indexID": "GJhQ1MrQnZkTFRR"
  }
];

var specialMembers = [{
    "dob": "12-12-1970",
    "firstName": "jimmy",
    "lasteName": "shew",
    "indexID": "RPT0ifQ"
  },
  {
    "dob": "18-10-1970",
    "firstName": "Timmy",
    "lasteName": "Doug",
    "indexID": "GJhQ1MrQ"
  },
  {
    "dob": "17-06-1981",
    "firstName": "John",
    "lasteName": "owascar",
    "indexID": "GJhQ1MrTGDSRQ"
  }
];

var indexIDs = [],
  mismatchIndexIDS = [],
  indexIdMismatchCounter = 0;


for (const rxInfo of rxInfos) {
  const member = specialMembers.find(member => member.indexID === rxInfo.indexID);
  if (member) {
    indexIDs.push(rxInfo.indexID);
    console.log('process', member);
  } else {
    mismatchIndexIDS.push(rxInfo.indexID);
    indexIdMismatchCounter++;
  }
}

console.log('index ids', indexIDs);
console.log('mismatches', mismatchIndexIDS);
console.log('counter', indexIdMismatchCounter);
```

Comment: i also wanted to get member element so i can further process the logic like in my code i have to assign member to proxyMember, in that case i have to use filter i think

Comment: @hussain I changed my answer to use `find` instead. This way, you get the member for a given ID.